# What's the difference between 'bundle exec jekyll serve' and 'jekyll serve'?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, bundler

I'm currently learning Jekyll, a framework for building websites, and I don't know what's the difference between `bundle exec jekyll serve` and `jekyll serve`. Both seem to behave the same.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In two words:

`bundle exec jekyll serve` - runs the exact jekyll server version that is specified in your Gemfile/Gemfile.lock.

`jekyll serve` - runs *some* version of jekyll server, which may or may not be the one you want.

For best results, always use `bundle exec`. On my machine, I have a shell alias for it, so that I can type

```
be jekyll serve
```

Comment: ...with an exact gemset specified in the `Gemfile`.